# How can I draw the diagram using few decoders for this truth table?

Tags: logic-gates, diagram, decoder, truth-table

[image]

For the truth table above, abc is the input and xyz is the output.

I do know how to draw the diagram using a decoder in case of when I have only one output.
How can I draw the diagram using a decoder when I have 3 outputs for this case?

This is what I am guessing 
[image]

After I apply the advice, here is what I have

[image]

Comment: Start by showing what you tried to solve it. It helps us to see where you're running into trouble, or just to feel like we're not doing your homework for you.

Comment: @andrewMacrae Yes, I just updated it with my guess!

Comment: For z, you do not need a decoder, as in z = c.

Comment: @andrewMacrae I appreciate your help! I tried based on what you said!

Comment: @stainlesssteelrat Got it. I could see z = c. What does it mean by the way? Do I still need to keep the or gate for z like above?

Comment: It just means there is no difference between z OR c, so no logic is needed.  c on one end of a line, z on the other.  Your instructor wants you to think about what logic design actually means.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat  okay. But, I am confused with "no logic is needed". Do you mean that I do not need to put any logic gate for z? So just do nothing for the z?..

Comment: A line with c on left and z on right. As in, no OR, no Mux,  just a line.

Comment: @stainlesssteelrat I truly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you nearly have it.

X is high if the input decodes to the '100 value, 
Y is high if it decodes to '010, '011, '101 or '110 and 
Z is high if it decodes to '001 '011 '101 or '111.

There is one error in your drawing: X, Y and Z are already your outputs. You don't need to "or" them together at the end.

[image: Label your outputs X,Y and Z and lose the last or gate]

Then take a look at the drawing and see if you can understand how the ABC decoders are redundant and how you can reuse the outputs from just one decoder to compute X, Y and Z so you only need one decoder.